# Bad: QEMU with PX4 Firmware

Tags: qemu

I studied how to set up `PX4` on `QEMU`.

Prior to creating the `stm32f427` board, I set the board `stm32-p103` supplied by the `QEMU` and use the kernel image as .elf file obtained by the `PX4 firmware.`

```
./arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M stm32-p103 -cpu cortex-m4 -kernel ~/src/Firmware/build/nuttx_px4fmu-v2_default/nuttx_px4fmu-v2_default.elf -gdb tcp::9000
```

But as soon as started, it hang..

Using `arm-none-eabi-gdb`, I checked what's problem and I found it stops at first instruction on `__start.`

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb nuttx_px4fmu-v2_default.
```

I thought it would work if the CPU spec and board didn't fit into this firmware, but it hasn't started.

Please help me...

Here's my code:

```
Breakpoint 1, __start ()
    at chip/stm32_start.c:243
243 {
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function __start:
=> 0x080041cc <+0>: push    {r3, lr}
   0x080041ce <+2>: bl  0x800424c <stm32_clockconfig>
   0x080041d2 <+6>: mrs r3, CONTROL
   0x080041d6 <+10>:    orr.w   r3, r3, #4
   0x080041da <+14>:    msr CONTROL, r3
   0x080041de <+18>:    ldr r2, [pc, #84]   ; (0x8004234 <__start+104>)
   0x080041e0 <+20>:    ldr r3, [r2, #0]
   0x080041e2 <+22>:    bic.w   r3, r3, #3221225472; 0xc0000000
   0x080041e6 <+26>:    str r3, [r2, #0]
   0x080041e8 <+28>:    sub.w   r2, r2, #428    ; 0x1ac
   0x080041ec <+32>:    ldr r3, [r2, #0]
   0x080041ee <+34>:    orr.w   r3, r3, #15728640   ; 0xf00000
   0x080041f2 <+38>:    str r3, [r2, #0]
   0x080041f4 <+40>:    bl  0x80045b4 <stm32_lowsetup>
   0x080041f8 <+44>:    bl  0x80043b4 <stm32_gpioinit>
   0x080041fc <+48>:    ldr r3, [pc, #56]   ; (0x8004238 <__start+108>)
   0x080041fe <+50>:    ldr r2, [pc, #60]   ; (0x800423c <__start+112>)
   0x08004200 <+52>:    movs    r1, #0
   0x08004202 <+54>:    cmp r3, r2
   0x08004204 <+56>:    bcc.n   0x8004222 <__start+86>
   0x08004206 <+58>:    ldr r2, [pc, #56]   ; (0x8004240 <__start+116>)
   0x08004208 <+60>:    ldr r3, [pc, #56]   ; (0x8004244 <__start+120>)
   0x0800420a <+62>:    ldr r1, [pc, #60]   ; (0x8004248 <__start+124>)
   0x0800420c <+64>:    cmp r3, r1
   0x0800420e <+66>:    bcc.n   0x8004228 <__start+92>
   0x08004210 <+68>:    bl  0x8004c68 <up_earlyserialinit>
   0x08004214 <+72>:    bl  0x80a465c <stm32_boardinitialize>
   0x08004218 <+76>:    movw    r1, #750    ; 0x2ee
   0x0800421c <+80>:    ldr r0, [pc, #28]   ; (0x800423c <__start+112>)
   0x0800421e <+82>:    bl  0x80041a8 <go_os_start>
   0x08004222 <+86>:    str.w   r1, [r3], #4
   0x08004226 <+90>:    b.n 0x8004202 <__start+54>
   0x08004228 <+92>:    ldr.w   r0, [r2, #4]!
   0x0800422c <+96>:    str.w   r0, [r3], #4
   0x08004230 <+100>:   b.n 0x800420c <__start+64>
   0x08004232 <+102>:   nop
<tinue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x08004234 <+104>:   and lr, r0, r4, lsr pc
   0x08004238 <+108>:   andcs   r0, r0, r0, lsl #28
   0x0800423c <+112>:   andcs   r5, r0, r8, lsl r10
   0x08004240 <+116>:   stmdaeq pc, {r2, r3, r4, r5, r9, r11, lr, pc}   ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
   0x08004244 <+120>:   andcs   r0, r0, r0
   0x08004248 <+124>:   andcs   r0, r0, r9, lsr #27
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: There's no "stm32-p103" board model in upstream QEMU. It might be best to ask whoever has written the code for that board. In general you shouldn't expect code written for one board to work on a different one.

Comment: Oh, I downloaded QEMU from https://github.com/pebble so that I can utilize `stm32-p103` board.